# How to save file via wordpad with cmd?

Tags: command-line, wordpad

I want to save a docx file as rtf file via wordpad, using cmd.

How can I do it?

Comment: Why? Are you looking to batch process? Do you not have MS word?

Comment: Beacuse I am making a vb.net app, and I want to convert doc files to rtf with it.

Comment: So you want to batch convert *docx* files to *rtf*? It looks like Wordpad and command line are completely irrelevant.

Comment: But I can use Wordpad to open docx and to save it as rtf. That's not a direct way, but it may work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's going to work for you, but it looks like a user at the blog/forum site MobileRead addressed/solved this issue using VB. Please see http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=138076

Comment: This code is for word macro, and it's not working on my vb.net app.